# How can I show two ActionResult in Home/index view MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two controllers

BloggsController:

```
   //Last blogg from the database
        public ActionResult LastBlogg()
        {
            var lastblogg = db.Bloggs.OrderByDescending(o => o.ID).Take(1);

            return View(lastblogg);
        }
```

DishesController:

```
//Last recipe from the database
public ActionResult LastRecipe()
{
    var last = db.Dishes.OrderByDescending(o => o.ID).Take(1);

    return View(last);
}
```

I want to show the result of this on my start-page, Views/Home/index.

If I put this in my HomeController:

```
//Last recipe from the database
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var last = db.Dishes.OrderByDescending(o => o.ID).Take(1);

    return View(last);
}
```

Can I show the result in of recipe on my start-page but how do I show both the result of the blogg and recipe on om startpage?

Answer (score 2):

You should create separate partial views for `LastBlogg` and `LastRecipe` and place both of them to your home page (new Model will be required).

Answer (score 1):

Create a View Model and add both Blogg and Recipe to it.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var lastRecipe = db.Dishes.OrderByDescending(o => o.ID).Take(1);
    var lastblogg = db.Bloggs.OrderByDescending(o => o.ID).Take(1);

   var model = new BloggRecipeModel(lastRecipe, lastblogg);

   return View(model);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a custom ViewData in your Models folder, like this:

```
public class MyCustomViewData
{
public Dish Dish {get;set;}
public Blog Blog {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
ViewData.Model = new MyCustomViewData
{
Dish = db.Dishes.OrderByDescending(o => o.ID).Take(1);
Blog = db.Bloggs.OrderByDescending(o => o.ID).Take(1);
}

return View();
```

And in your view, set the @Model property to Models.MyCustomViewData and handle it accordingly.